After the whole ride track using Mapbox, I want to show the route of the user which he has taken
It was working in older version and below sharing the code which I was using.
Below is the code I used in version 8.6.0:
val boundsList = LatLngBounds.Builder()

for (i in 0 until rideTrack.latlongArray.size) {
    if (rideTrack.latlongArray[i].lat != null && rideTrack.latlongArray[i].lat.isNotEmpty() &&
        rideTrack.latlongArray[i].long != null && rideTrack.latlongArray[i].long.isNotEmpty()) {
        val latitude = rideTrack.latlongArray[i].lat.toDouble()
        val longitude = rideTrack.latlongArray[i].long.toDouble()
        boundsList.include(LatLng(latitude, longitude))
    }
}     

mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundsList.build(),
                        (binding.mapboxView.height * 0.07f).toInt()))

could anyone check and share us how this can be done in the latest version 11.2.2.
We are expecting a the view of whole route that user has taken. And don't want to use the direction API to draw the route.
